# Detecting Game Event

Tags: windows, screen-scraping, screenshot, detection

I am trying to create a program to monitor a game and detect when a specific player (me) gets a kill.

I am specifically looking at Dota2.  When a kill occurs, the name of the killer and victim is displayed as text on the screen (see link to in-game screenshot).

[image]

I am completely at a loss as to how to start figuring this out.  What are some suggestions on how to accomplish this?  I am guessing that I'd have to make a program that grabs a screenshot every specified time interval and parses all on-screen text to determine whether or not I got the kill.  However, I don't even know if I am going in the right direction or even how to execute that.

I am very open-minded when it comes to specific languages or frameworks.  I'd just like to get this project off the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Well i've been working on something similar as well.
I think there might be 2 solutions.

1. Connect a bot to the game and parse messages from the game protocol. The bot receives each package from the game server that tells it to show the message with the kill made.
2. Create a dissecting program for this particular game and save its data into a db. Then do whatever you want with the db.

There's also a solution that doesn't work for live games : having the replay parsed and showing it's messages.